# How to append the one aspx page to another aspx page?

Tags: asp.net

I have a requirement like as below:
      I have two aspx pages like firstpage.aspx and secondPage.aspx.
I have to append the secondPage.aspx form into firstPage.aspx, whenever page load happens. How can i achieve this one.
Could any one help me please.

Comment: You could create a page with two `ASCX` user controls and add them both to one `ASPX` page.

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for is structurally incorrect. ASP.NET has many ways to combine elements, but never two complete pages as you would have two HTML bodies and headers which would not make sense.

In ASP.NET you can use master pages to contain header and footer HTML and code that is used by one or many pages.

You can also create custom web controls that can be statically or dynamically loaded onto a page. This sounds the closest to what you want. You could have a customer address control and an ordering control and load them on the same page.

If the page content is hand-written text just write both onto the same page. If the page content is dynamically loaded from a database load the content for both pages onto the same page.

Comment: Thanks for You feed back. I understood that one. But my requirement is like that. I want to get secondPage entire form into firstpage form.

Comment: Do you mean that you have some form controls on secondPage that you want including on firstPage? Create a custom control with the form from secondPage on, then replace the form on secondPage with your new control and add the new control to firstPage in the right place. The point of custom controls is to have reusable HTML and backend code that can be added to multiple pages. By using custom controls we get reliable tested units of functionality that can be reused on multiple pages.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try that one. Thanks for your suggestion. May be it will work.